# Sliding window for coco annotated dataset

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a model with a dataset of large images (20.000px) with the purpose to detect anomalies.

Because faults can be very small, I use a sliding window method to cut the images in blocks of 448x488px (with the SAHI python package).

I encouter the following problem:
every fault is annotated with a polygon. But as you can see, the polygon is a bit larger than the fault itself. So now the sliding window (red) has an overlap with the polygon (blue). This means that window is classified as faulty, while in fact it is correct.

[image: Sliding window example]

Now this effects the accuracy, recall and precision scores. I thought of using a minimum area annotation treshold on each window, but that wouldn't be possible since some faults are really small.

Also tried making the annotations more precise, this caused an increase of 20% recall.

Are there good practices for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

> I thought of using a minimum area annotation treshold on each window,
> but that wouldn't be possible since some faults are really small.

This, but adjust your minimum area calculation such that it only relates to the area of your fault area (in my code box 1 - blue colour).

```
union_area = (box1[2] - box1[0]) * (box1[3] - box1[1])
```

**Full code with additional scaffolding so it will be easy for you to experiment with your own customized IoU equation and specification.**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as patches

def calculate_iou(box1, box2, use_custom_union=True):
    # Box format: (x1, y1, x2, y2)
    x1_i = max(box1[0], box2[0])
    y1_i = max(box1[1], box2[1])
    x2_i = min(box1[2], box2[2])
    y2_i = min(box1[3], box2[3])

    intersection_area = max(0, x2_i - x1_i) * max(0, y2_i - y1_i)

    if use_custom_union:
        # Customize the union to be related to only one bounding box (box1 in this case)
        union_area = (box1[2] - box1[0]) * (box1[3] - box1[1])
    else:
        # Regular union considering both bounding boxes
        union_area = (box1[2] - box1[0]) * (box1[3] - box1[1]) + (box2[2] - box2[0]) * (box2[3] - box2[1]) - intersection_area

    iou = intersection_area / union_area
    return iou


def visualize_boxes(box1, box2):
    plt.figure()

    # Plot box1
    plt.plot([box1[0], box1[2], box1[2], box1[0], box1[0]], [box1[1], box1[1], box1[3], box1[3], box1[1]], label='Box1', color='blue')

    # Plot box2
    plt.plot([box2[0], box2[2], box2[2], box2[0], box2[0]], [box2[1], box2[1], box2[3], box2[3], box2[1]], label='Box2', color='red')

    plt.xlabel('X-axis')
    plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

# Example bounding boxes
box1 = [4, 4, 6, 5]
box2 = [5, 4, 10, 8]

# Calculate IoU with custom union
iou_custom_union = calculate_iou(box1, box2, use_custom_union=True)
print(f"IoU with custom union: {iou_custom_union}")

# Calculate IoU with regular union for comparison
iou_regular_union = calculate_iou(box1, box2, use_custom_union=False)
print(f"IoU with regular union: {iou_regular_union}")

# Visualize bounding boxes
visualize_boxes(box1, box2)
```

**Exemplary visualization as defined in the above code.**
[image: Customized union]

**How does it work now?**
With the customized equation you will get an IoU of 0.5 (meaning 50% of the fault is within the box - **which is easy and intuitive to threshold for you.**

Instead of 0.0476% for the regular IoU which, as you experienced makes it hard to set a threshold.